# Need to customize Node Red Editor Client CSS and JS, where to find documentation about source code of node-red-editor?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, customization, node-red

I need some help to modify the files:

- **red.min.js** file located at: ~ npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules@node-red\editor-client\public\red
- **style.min.css** file located at: ~ npm\node_modules\node-red\node_modules@node-red\editor-client\public\red

but I can't find any information or documentation on the functions and styles of the node red editor, the main purpose is to make the node palette sidebar resizable see the image example:

[image]

I have thought about reusing part of the code used for:

`<div id = "red-ui-sidebar">`

I hope for ideas and thanks for taking the time to read.

Aditional notes: To install Node-Red run:

`npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red`

**Update** 13/12/2020

Added Events

- Added `RED.events.on("palette:resize", workspace_tabs.resize);`
- Added `RED.events.on("palette:resize", resizeNavBorder);`
- Added `RED.events.on("palette:resize", resizeStack);`
- Added `RED.events.on("palette:resize", handleWindowResize);`

Added HTML

- Added `'<div id="red-ui-palette-separator"></div>' +` in foo buildEditor

Added CSS

- Added `#red-ui-palette-separator {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 189px; bottom: 0px; width: 7px; z-index: 11; background: #f3f3f3 url(images/grip.png) no-repeat 50% 50%; cursor: col-resize; border-color: #bbb; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #bbb; }`
- Added `.red-ui-palette-closed > #red-ui-palette-separator {left: 0px !important;}`
- Added `z-index: 12;` to .red-ui-sidebar-control-left
- Added `left: 189px;` to #red-ui-workspace
- Added `border-color: #bbb; box-sizing: border-box;` to #red-ui-sidebar-separator

Added JS

(to foo init inside palette prop of RED)

- Added `var paletteSeparator = {}; paletteSeparator.dragging = false;`
- Added `setupPaletteSeparator();`
- Added `RED.popover.tooltip($("#red-ui-palette-separator").find(".red-ui-palette-control-left"), RED._("keyboard.togglePalette"), "core:toggle-palette");`

**Whats works**

- Palette separator displays correctly and preserves styles
- Palette separator toggle on / off in corrected position
- Palette toggle button is displayed above the palette separator to simplify functionality
- The palette separator is now draggable and in toggle on / of remenber the last position

**What I need? :**

- On function Start event handle Palette resize event
- On function Drag event resize the Palette and Workspace
- On function Stop event update resized Palette and Workspace

**Any help would be apreciated**

```
function setupPaletteSeparator() {
        
        $("#red-ui-palette-separator").draggable({
             
              axis: "x",

              start: function (event, ui) {
                
              },

              drag: function (event, ui) {

              },

              stop: function (event, ui) {
                
              },

        });
         
 }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to modify node-reds internal files? Or are you hoping to copy-paste some of its internal logic for your own custom nodes, because you want behavior similar to it?

Comment: probably opt for that

Answer (score 0):

The doc for how to theme the Node-RED editor is [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/configuration#editor-themes).

It lets you use the `settings.js` file to replace/supplement the shipped CSS and to include your own custom script files using the `editorTheme` entry

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the configuration file the possibility of importing other scripts is established, with the configuration  ``` editorTheme: {page: { // Absolute path to custom script files
            scripts: [],
        },}``` absolute to hardrive files structure or node-red directory ?

Comment: Absolute means just that, a fully qualified path

Comment: in that case I must choose the hard way and modify the node-red internal existing code